# Can't open IE using selenium in python

Tags: python, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am running on a Windows 10 machine, Internet Explorer 11, python 3.6, selenium 3.4.3 with IEDriverServer 3.5. I am trying to open up IE using the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os


driverLocation = "C:\\Users\\JD\\PycharmProjects\\Lib\\IEDriverServer.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.ie.driver"] = driverLocation
driver = webdriver.Ie(driverLocation)
google = "https://google.com"
driver.get(google)
```

The output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/J/PycharmProjects/Automation/IE_Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie(driverLocation)
  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 57, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unknown capability named platform
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

UPDATE:
I added this to my previous code,

```
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
print(capabilities["platform"])
print(capabilities["browserName"])
```

OUTPUT:

```
WINDOWS
internet explorer
 File "C:\Users\JD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Invalid capabilities in alwaysMatch: unknown capability named platform
```

UPDATE:
I have also tried setting the capabilities but still recieve the same error: "unknown capabilities named platform

```
caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER.copy()
caps["platform"] = "WINDOWS"
caps["browserName"] = "internet explorer"
caps["requireWindowFocus"] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps,
                       executable_path="C:\\Users\\JD\\PycharmProjects\\Lib\\IEDriverServer.exe")
browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem for couple of days. 
My workaround for this was to delete `platform` and `version` keys from `capabilities` dictionary

Example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

#create capabilities
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER

#delete platform and version keys
capabilities.pop("platform", None)
capabilities.pop("version", None)

#start an instance of IE
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path="C:\\your\\path\\to\\IEDriverServer.exe", capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

My guess, so far, is that this error happens because w3c_caps are passed as the only right capabilities. You can see that in the Traceback:

> `response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)`

when you click on it you will see that:

```
w3c_caps["alwaysMatch"].update(capabilities)
```

As you can see [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html) _W3C_CAPABILITY_NAMES hold different values than the ones we are passing. 
We are passing "WINDOWS" as "platform", while _W3C_CAPABILITY_NAMES has "platformName" and accepts only small caps. Same goes for "version" key.

So we were adding capabilities that are not recognized.

This workaround is by no means perfect, and I was able to start IE in selenium java without deleting some of the capabilities.

**EDIT:** Another solution can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808) in Grimlek comment, which essentially says that you should delete `"capabilities": w3c_caps` from `start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile=None)` (from remote\webdriver.py). Code looks like this:

```
w3c_caps["alwaysMatch"].update(capabilities)
parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
                      "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
```

Then you would not need to delete keys from capabilities.

**ANOTHER EDIT:** I have just updated my selenium-python from  3.4.3 to 3.5.0 and there's no longer need for messing with capabilities.